# C# listBox.SelectedIndex from Database

Tags: c#, listbox, selectedindex

In visual Studio 2010 (using visual C#),I have a form where there is a listBox (named listBox1). The user selects one of the items displayed on the listBox and then clicks on a Save Button. The application saves the user's selection into a Database using:

`cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table2 (kat) values ('"+listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()+"')"`

(edit)For instance they are saved as 0 or 1 or 2 etc...

And then I want the application to use that `int` to select the same item on another listBox,with the exactly same items but on another form.

What I have so far is:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1 WHERE username='"+textBox1.Text+"'";
                                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                if (dr.HasRows)
                                {
                                    while (dr.Read())
                                    {
                                        form1.listBox1.SelectedIndex(dr[0]);
                                    }

                                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting value as `String` in the database, and then trying to add values as `Integer` the wrong way

to properly insert value as integer

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1(kat) VALUES(@id)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", listBox1.SelectedIndex);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The to create the copy of the listBox on other form you can do so by using a `SELECT` query.

Ex.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT kat FROM Table1";

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    otherListBox.Items.Add(reader[0]);
}
reader.Close();
```

---

To sync the list , try this

```
int index = listBox1.FindStringExact("id to find");

if (index > -1)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: also while reading from the database, you can use `int.parse(dr[0].ToString());`.

Comment: There is no need for `Int32.Parse` as the value is inserted as INT rather than STRING

Comment: I don't really care if they are saved as an int or a string(edited it). I don't know how to retrieve them

Comment: @NickShev - check the second part of the answer! it shows how

Comment: @NickShev: I would suggest that you get the selected index value from the DB in a separate variable. For the second list, you can just bind the same list of values as you did for the 1st list. But after the binding is over, you will just call `secondList.SelectedIndex=variable`.
where you will get variable from the DB and then use that to select the item in the UI list.

Comment: @AppDeveloper  But doesn't that Add a new Item? The otherListBox already contains the same Items and I need the application to select one of them

Comment: @NickShev - conditional select ?

Comment: if you just need to select one of them then you can set it like `listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0`

Comment: @AppDeveloper sorry,meant to say to select the one that was selected in the previous form, the one whose string I've saved on my DB. Basically I have the string on the DB and I don't know how to use it to select the specific Item of the otherListBox

Comment: @AppDeveloper in FindStringExact("id to find")  I add a query? like the exact column from the DB?